# I have some problems with masm

Tags: windows, assembly, cmd, tasm, dosbox

I have some problems with masm when I want to run:

```
CSEG segment
org 100h

Begin:
    mov ah, 9 
    mov dx, offset Message
    int 21h
    ;mov ah, 9 
    ;mov dx, offset mess2
    ;int 21h

    int 20h
mess2 db 'It is me$'
Message db 'Hello, World2243!$'
CSEG ends
end Begin
```

It prints:

[Smth like: ||=It's me!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I06Vt.png)

But I commented this string out!!
I compile this code on DosBox, maybe that's the cause

Comment: According to the screenshot, you're using TASM, not MASM.

Comment: The fact that you're using `org 100h` suggests that you should be producing a COM file rather than an EXE, i.e. you should use the `/t` linker option.

Comment: You didn't comment out *the string*, that's why it's there in memory which makes it possible for it to get printed when your program runs wrong.  You only commented out the instructions that reference it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, you use `tasm`, not `masm`. These are two different things, see [tasm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Assembler) and [masm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Macro_Assembler)
In order to print two lines, I used the code:

```
MODEL   TINY
STACK 100h  
DATASEG
    Hellostr DB 'Hello First Step Site $'
    str2     DB 'Step 16 $'
CODESEG     
start:  
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
    mov dx,offset Hellostr               
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
    mov dx,offset  str2
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
    mov ah,04Ch
    mov al,1h
    int 21h
end start
```

compile + build + run:

```
mount c C:\path\to\asm\file\PROGRA~1.asm
c:
tasm PROGRA~1.asm
tlink /3 PROGRA~1.obj 
PROGRA~1.exe
```

result:[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRbxT.jpg)
I will also note, as indicated in the screenshot above, I have a `dosbox` version `0.74-3`
And lastly: I advise you to look VERY carefully at the screenshot you provided.